# SQL Server Reporting Services - suppress empty line in free-form report

Tags: reporting-services, reportingservices-2005

I have a free-form report based on a `List` control in SQL Server Reporting Services, basically displaying an address for a company:

```
Company Name
Address 1
Address 2
ZipCode City
```

However, some of my company records don't have a value for the `Address2` field - in which case, I'd like to completely remove the line (i.e. `Textbox`) which contains the non-existant `Address2` data - so it should look something like:

```
Company Name
Address 1
ZipCode City
```

I can set the `Hidden` attribute of the `Textbox` on the report just fine - however that only results in the textbox being hidden - and a blank line shows up where `Address2` used to be.... I'd like to **suppress** that blank line. ***HOW?!?!***

I'm not inside a Tablix or anything like that - it's just free-form textboxes on a report. Any chance to get this to do what I'm trying to do without a huge effort?

Comment: What is the form for your data? Parameters, or a dataset?

Comment: I know I'm late to the party, but did you consider just placing these all into one textbox, as placeholders including linebreaks? The placeholder for Address 2 could only include the line break if Address 2 was not empty.

Comment: @JamieF: I tried the solution that Ian suggested, but in the end, we did something like you're suggesting here. Seemed to work just a tad better overall (less overhead)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, it can be done, kind of, depending on what you need. Is it a huge effort? Up to you to decide:

First I created a dataset.

```
select company = 'A'
, add1 = 'Add 1 A'
, add2 = 'Add 2 A'
, zip = '90210'
union all
select company = 'B'
, add1 = 'Add 1 B'
, add2 = null
, add3 = '12345'
```

Next, create a **List** and group it by *Company*.

[image]

In this **List** add a **Table** with rows for each field. In each of these rows you add a **Rectangle**, then a **Textbox** with the field details. Since we have a **Table** we can hide rows based on an expression, and because there is a **Rectangle** in each row we can move the **Texbox** around as required:

[image]

In the second address row, set the row visibility based on an expression:

```
=IIf(IsNothing(Fields!add2.Value), true, false)
```

Final result:

[image]

You can move the fields around as required. It's not perfect and a bit fiddly, but at least this will give you a bit more flexibility and maybe an idea on how you might like to proceed if it's not 100% suitable.

Comment: Thanks - smart approach and great idea !

Answer (score 8):

Put all fields in one line and check before each field if you need a line feed.

For example:

```
[Name1]«Expr»[Name2]«Expr»[Name3]
[Street]
[City]
```

With Expressions:

```
=Iif(Fields!Name2.Value="",Nothing,vbCRLF)
=Iif(Fields!Name3.Value="",Nothing,vbCRLF)
```

Answer (score 0):

Just put this expression in my textbox.  (Allows you to include all the other address field before and after it in the same textbox.)  Super easy!

=iif(Fields!Street2.Value is nothing, Fields!Street1.Value, Fields!Street1.Value + vbCRLF + Fields!Street2.Value)